# Почему может не запускаться Handler?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть класс который наследует от Runnable

```
public class SentZip implements Runnable {
@Override
public void run() {
    while (true){

    }
}
```

и есть main в котором я запускаю этот Runnable через Handler

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Handler handler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    handler = new Handler();
}

public void send1(View view) {
    handler.post(new SentZip());
}

public void send2(View view) {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new SentZip());
    thread.start();
}
```

И для теста я повесил на экран ProgressBar чтоб крутился и показывал зависает экран или нет...

И вот когда я запускаю метод send1 то экран зависает, а когда send2 то нет... Вроде правильно запускаю Handler, почему он занимает основной поток?

Вот так получается с Handler

```
public void send(View view) {
    HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("one", HandlerThread.NORM_PRIORITY);
    Looper mLooper = handlerThread.getLooper();

    ----> Handler handler = new Handler(mLooper);

    handler.post(new SentZip());
    handlerThread.start();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Потому что `Handler` выполняет `Runnable` в том потоке к которому присоединен его `Looper`, а дефолтный конструктор `new Handler()` создаёт `Handler` с `Looper`'ом потока в котором был вызван.

---

В общем вот так надо

```
public void send(View view) {
    HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("one", HandlerThread.NORM_PRIORITY);
    handlerThread.start(); // только после этого у потока появится лупер

    Handler handler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());
    handler.post(new SentZip());
}
```

Comment: А как нужно указать `Looper` чтоб это работало правильно?

Comment: Ну в вашем случае правильно юзать send2. Смысла использовать Handler я не вижу. А так вообще для запуска ранаблов в отдельном потоке надо создать этот поток используя класс HandlerThread, запустить его, а затем использовать его лупер при создании хандлера.

Comment: Добавил в ответ как вы сказали, но у меня все равно не работает... Что я сделал не так?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko вы забыли сделать `handlerThread.start();` после создания потока.

Comment: Добавил в вопрос изменения, но все равно не работает(( Вот такую ошибку пишет Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.os.MessageQueue android.os.Looper.mQueue' on a null object reference

Comment: Дополнил ответ рабочим вариантом, раз уж вы гуглом пользоваться совсем не умеете.